# SetProperty Driver Command Line Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, java

So I'm trying to run my script through a command line so it works on other computers.

The problem is that I have this hard-coded into it.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/xxxx/Desktop/chromedriver");
```

I want to be able to run it without that line so I can just call the driver through the command line, is that possible?

This is what I was attempting to use to try and run it.

```
java -jar ~/Desktop/driver.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Jar/chromedriver
```

But I get an error telling me the driver does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came back to this question a lot later. I ended up coming up with a solution to run my script through a command line to start the server.

java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar for windows just add a .exe after chromedriver

Answer (score 2):

You can get the driver path from the command line.

If you are using Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", args[0]);
}
```

Or you can distribute a Chrome driver in your project and call it using relative path.

```
String projectPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String projectPathToTheDriver = ...;
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",projectPath + projectPathToTheDriver + "chromedriver");
```

Comment: I've tried to use your code in the first line but I get an error.        
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Comment: Have you passed the path as an argument to the Java program?

Something like: java yourMainClassName /Users/userName/Desktop/chromedriver

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

If you just call java yourMainClassName, the args arrays will be empty - because you passed no argument.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question, which was how to do this from the command line. i.e. if you're a PHP dev using Codeception this is wrong.

Comment: Jim, your comment makes no sense. The question asks how to make a Java program deal with arguments passed through command-line. If you are using other technologies, you will probably have a different approach.